# FileNotFoundException open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) on Android Emulator

Tags: android

Following is the code where activity is erroring out  :
the error happens at line **outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void layoutToJPG(View v) {
        View screen = v.getRootView();
// or I've also tried: View screen = new View(this);
        screen.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap b = screen.getDrawingCache();
        Log.d("bitmap", b.toString());
        File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
        File file = new File(path, "/sample.jpg");
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved to Gallery.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            outputStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Error :

```
 W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)

W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/sample.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:235)
```

The above is the error I am getting. I am running it on android emulator **Pixel XL API 29**
Does it require some special permissions to save file on the emulator.

Comment: Hey! Verify if you are adding the permissions in the manifest file and if you are trying to save files, you should be use fileprovider

Comment: `I am running it on android emulator Pixel XL API 29 Does it require some special permissions to save file on the emulator.` Yes, it needs yet some special permission for an Android 10 device or emulator. Nobody mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

As.

> Android's permission system is one of the biggest security concern all
> along since those permissions are asked for at install time. Once
> installed, the application will be able to access all of things
> granted without any user's acknowledgement what exactly application
> does with the permission.
>
> Android 6.0 Marshmallow introduces one of the largest changes to the
> permissions model with the addition of runtime permissions, a new
> permission model that replaces the existing install time permissions
> model when you target API 23 and the app is running on an Android 6.0+
> device

**Try this code.**

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        1);
            }
        }
```

Add this in **Menifest**:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add permission. And, ask user to accept permission.

Manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Request permission :

There's a [library](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter) which you can use to ask for permission

```
Dexter.withContext(this)
.withPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
.withListener(new PermissionListener() {
    @Override public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {/* ... */}
    @Override public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {/* ... */}
    @Override public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {/* ... */}
}).check();
```

Over than API level 23(maybe, I actually forgot) you have to request user to grant permission. That's why you have to add above source code.